# Export selected orders

Tags: orders, export

In Magento 1 admin sales grid, there's a function to export to CSV.
How can I only export selected orders instead of exporting ALL the orders?

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter the records first for example by **date**,**order amount**,**status** etc. then you can export it.

Hope this helps you.